# Testing Android WorkManager weekly, monthly and yearly PeriodicWorkRequest

Tags: android

My app has weekly, monthly and yearly PeriodicWorkRequests with no constraints which needs to be tested on an android phone,
Assume I start a weekly work at 15th Dec 2020 8am, I need to test if it's repeated at 22nd Dec 2020 around 8am, I verified it's executed at first time(15th) and then I changed the phone time to 22nd Dec 2020 7:59am and waited for about 5 mins, it's not starting the second iteration.

Any help in testing this functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from 2.4.0 to 2.5.0-beta02 worked

```
//def work_version = "2.4.0"

def work_version = "2.5.0-beta02"

// (Java only)
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```